# Remove Moderator Notification Limit during SuperUser Beta

Tags: feature-request

I agree and respect the Moderator notification limit on the site for flagging content.

However during the SuperUser Beta can this be lifted. There is a few questions that need to be  reviewed, and I for one ran out of my flag limit. During Beta I think it is important to be able to flag more then the normal amount of questions?

Comment: Is this necessarily related to new beta sites?? If you join a closed beta, they give you a bunch of privileges. I got them (for life hacks) but never got to use them. Is there a flag limit in there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You flag questions because people don't mark it as CW?

Oh my...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5628

Comment: At the moment there is no moderators or users with enough rep to handle this except for the OP's. Some users don't understand how to do it. I was using it as an example.